# Sonata admin non-deprecated method for setting templates?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

The documentation for Sonata Admin Bundle offers this method for setting per-admin templates:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/templates.html

However that method has now been deprecated. Is there a new method, not mentioned yet in the documentation, or have the devs simply jumped the gun with this deprecation?

Comment: This is an old post, but just in case ...
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/6766
... So the decrepation has been moved to 5.0.
The next one 4.0 which is coming soon will still support the old setTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

You can define your custom template for each admin by using the following code in your admin class.

```
public function configure()
{
    $this->setTemplate('show', 'sonata_admin/show.html.twig');
    // similarly for all actions
}
```

You must place your twig file in **templates/sonata_admin/** folder, if you are using symfony 4.

The twig file must be like,

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/show.html.twig' %}

{% block block_name %}
//your content
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I asked how to AVOID that method. Quoting the documentation I linked to in the question is a bad answer.